# Error 26 - how to resolve in connection to DB?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, connection, firewall

I get this error:

> **System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException**:
> A network related or instance error has occurred while establishing a connection to the SQL Server. The server cannot be found or is unavailable. Verify that the instance name is correct and that the SQL Server configuration allows remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error locating the specified server / instance)

How to resolve this problem? I apply in firewall advanced permissions and nothing effects. Could we help me? Please!

Comment: May I suggest you post your connection string?

Comment: Follow the troubleshooting guide from the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I would try to connect with SQL Server management studio before attempting in c#.  The parameters in your connection string are not compatible with the SQL Server you are using (or credentials are wrong).

Comment: You really should edit the question to include your connection string (replace name/address, username and password of course). `error: 26 - Error locating the specified server / instance` usually indicates that the SQL Browser service is not accessible on the host server via UDP port 1434. When checking the firewall rules did you see ingress rules for udp/1434?